# Qgis 3.x: Python error when adding scripts to processing toolbox

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

When I add a script (any script) to QGIS 3.x I get the following Python error:

```
NameError: name 'Uitvoermap' is not defined 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\script\ScriptAlgorithmProvider.py", line 111, in loadAlgorithms
    alg = ScriptUtils.loadAlgorithm(moduleName, filePath)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\script\ScriptUtils.py", line 68, in loadAlgorithm
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
  File "", line 728, in exec_module
  File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\michi\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\processing\scripts\garmin.py", line 6, in 
    Uitvoermap += "\\"
NameError: name 'Uitvoermap' is not defined


Python versie: 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS versie: 3.4.4-Madeira Madeira, f6ddc62fdb 

Python pad:
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python
C:/Users/michi/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:/Users/michi/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python/plugins
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.4\bin\python37.zip
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.4\bin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:/Users/michi/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
```

The script works for others. I tried other proven scripts with the same result.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.